# reactjs view got messed up when fetching data

Tags: reactjs

i have problems on reactjs.

the problem is my component rendered before it fetch the data so that makes some class lost its style. but if i reload the page while inspecting it (chrome inspect element) it loads properly.

with inspecting
[while inspecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foz7n.png)

without inspecting

[without inspecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOitj.png)

please help me. if i hardcode it(without using .map) it works fine.

code (i dont think its helpful)

```
 var produk = products.slice(0,4).map(products =>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 special-grid best-seller">
          <div className="products-single fix">
              <div className="box-img-hover">
                  <div className="type-lb">
                      <p className="sale">{products.tipe}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="imageboks" style={{height:"18vh", width:"28vh"}}>
                  <img src={'images/esport/'+products.gambar1} className="img-fluid" alt="Image" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mask-icon">
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View"><i className="fas fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Compare"><i className="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Add to Wishlist"><i className="far fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <a className="cart" href="#"> {new Intl.DateTimeFormat("id", {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "long",
          day: "2-digit"
        }).format(products.firstSale)}</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="why-text">
                  <h4>{products.judul}</h4>
                  {products.harga === 0 ? <h5>Gratis</h5> : <h5><NumberFormat value={products.harga} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'Rp. '}/></h5>}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

return code

```
  <div className="row special-list">
                {produk}


              </div>
```

Comment: May be you are applying styles, before data lode, try to apply it after successfully data load.

Comment: @RameshReddy done

Comment: @swapnilsolanke i applied it on index.blade in laravel views